# What kind of a measurement variable are these?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, ordinal-data, measurement

Can anyone please explain what kind of a measurement variable these are?

1. Facebook Pictures - I feel that these should be nominal but if
   there is a date stamp on the images, then it would be ordinal. Also,
   if you're considering images as a matrix of pixels, then you can
   perform an arithmetic operation on it making it ratio variable.
2. Educational Background - I feel this is ordinal as you can order it based on the
   qualification.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a homework?

Comment: Welcome to this community! There's no universal answer to your question. It depends on what your inference is about, what kind of decisions you must make, which software or hardware is available to you, and so on... If someone told me "I'm using Facebook pictures as a measurement variable" I'd ask "what do you mean??"

Answer (score 1):

Ordinal, nominal and such categorizations are best suited for stuff that goes into cells in structured, tabular data, like a typical Excel sheet.

As you point out, an image is a more complex type of data. In fact it's a table by itself whose pixel values can be categorized in that way.

And as you noted, one can extract features from images (e.g. image size, average pixel value, location, ...) that can go into the typical tabular form (Excel sheet) above mentioned. Then the categorizations apply. Even then, as others have pointed out, the categorizations can be fuzzy and should be done depending on the problem requirements.